# Clone is duplicating multiple times, when I just want one

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click duplicate it duplicates the row fine, but when I click it again I get another 2, then 4 etc, how can I stop this from happening and just clone one div on each click...

Jquery:

```
<script>

    $(".clonable-button").bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var section = $(this).data('clone');
        var parent = $('[data-id="' + section + '"]');
        var sequence = 0;

        if(!$(this).data('last')) {
            sequence = $(parent).find('.cloneable').last().data('id');
        } else {
            sequence = $(this).data('last');
        }

        $(this).data('last', ++sequence);

        $(parent).append(parent.html());

    });

    $('.clone-wrapper').on('click', '.clone-remove',function(){
        var parent = $(this).parents('.cloneable');
        $(parent).remove();
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
        <div class="clone-wrapper" data-id="skill">
            <div class="row cloneable" data-id="0">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="skill_name_0">Skills and Qualifications Titles </label>
                        <input id="skill_name_0" placeholder="ex : PHP, WordPress" name="skill[0][name]" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="skill_percentage_0">Job Position </label>
                        <input id="skill_percentage_0" placeholder="ex : 90" name="skill[0][percentage]" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-right clone-remove" data-last="">
                    <div class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-clone="skill">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove Skill </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="white-space-20"></div>
        <div class="row text-right">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="btn btn-default btn-sm clonable-button" id="skill">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Skill </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I just want the following code duplicated once on each click

```
            <div class="row cloneable" data-id="0">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="skill_name_0">Skills and Qualifications Titles </label>
                        <input id="skill_name_0" placeholder="ex : PHP, WordPress" name="skill[0][name]" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="skill_percentage_0">Job Position </label>
                        <input id="skill_percentage_0" placeholder="ex : 90" name="skill[0][percentage]" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-right clone-remove" data-last="">
                    <div class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-clone="skill">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove Skill </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your event listeners are getting duplicated and firing more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
var parent = $('[data-id="' + section + '"]');
```

Each time you append new block with the same data-id number of elements that match this selector increases. So to avoid this you have make the selector more specific. Like:

```
var parent = $('[data-id="' + section + '"]:last');
```

Also there is a jQuery method to clone the element. So change your line from:

```
$(parent).append(parent.html());
```

to:

```
parent.append(parent.clone());
```

That will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the click event multiple times somehow, You should either use a delegated event handler or use the `off` method like below.

```
$(".clonable-button").off('click').on('click', function(e){
```